# Decline an already pushed update,

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

I approved .net framework update on my WSUS server. Those updates have been pushed to the domain machines but have not been installed yet. They are waiting in the system tray waiting to installed.

This update should never have been approved. They update will cause custom enterprise software to stop running. I have made a mistake and need to reverse this process. How can I recall this update or stop it from running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The updates are stored in a cache in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.
By deleting the contents of the cache I was able to remove that update. First Windows Update service needed to be stopped.

I wrote a batch file to stop the service delete the cache on all servers.

The process works as follows.

Create .txt file with all the server name individually on one line.

Created .bat file called PurgeWsusCache.bat
This is what the batch contains

```
net stop wuauserv
cd /d %windir%
rd /s /Q SoftwareDistribution
net start wuauserv
```

Created .bat file called Run.bat
This is what the batch contains

```
@echo off
cd C:\scripts\PurgeWsusCache
psexec @computers.txt -c C:\scripts\PurgeWsusCache\PurgeWsusCache.bat
```

Run Run.bat

Comment: Also, make sure that you decline the update in WSUS, else it will just pop-up again. Just for other users using this as a reference :)